# Load jndi.xml before beans.xml

Tags: spring, apache-servicemix

I have two files beans.xml and jndi.xml. We want to retrieve something in beans.xml that is put into JNDI through jndi.xml. Unfortunately, beans in beans.xml are created before jndi.xml is loaded, so when we try to do the JNDI lookup in beans.xml, nothing is in JNDI. Is there a way to get jndi.xml to be loaded before beans.xml?

beans.xml

```
...
<bean id="geronimoTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction" />
</bean>
...
```

jndi.xml

```
<beans>
    <bean id="jndi"
          class="org.apache.xbean.spring.jndi.SpringInitialContextFactory"
          factory-method="makeInitialContext"
          singleton="true">
        <property name="entries" ref="jndiEntries" />
    </bean>

    <map id="jndiEntries">
        <entry key="java:comp/UserTransaction" value-ref="geronimoTransactionManager" />
    </map>

    <bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="geronimoTransactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="geronimoTransactionManager" class="org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl" />
</beans>
```

Here is the log that makes me believe beans.xml is loaded before jndi.xml.

```
21:43:26,927 | INFO  | l Console Thread | ultOsgiApplicationContextCreator | 72 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.0 | Discovered configurations {osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml} in bundle [SWIM Prototype :: AqMqJDBC Pooling (camel-osgi-aqmq)]
21:43:26,939 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 | OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext  | 61 - org.springframework.context - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Refreshing OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=camel-osgi-aqmq, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml): startup date [Wed Apr 20 21:43:26 GMT+00:00 2011]; root of context hierarchy
21:43:26,939 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 | OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext  | 61 - org.springframework.context - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Unpublishing application context OSGi service for bundle SWIM Prototype :: AqMqJDBC Pooling (camel-osgi-aqmq)
21:43:26,973 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 | XmlBeanDefinitionReader          | 59 - org.springframework.beans - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Loading XML bean definitions from URL [bundleentry://202.fwk22939763/META-INF/spring/beans.xml]
21:43:27,295 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 | CamelNamespaceHandler            | 75 - org.apache.camel.camel-spring - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | OSGi environment detected.
21:43:29,167 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 | WaiterApplicationContextExecutor | 72 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.0 | No outstanding OSGi service dependencies, completing initialization for OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=camel-osgi-aqmq, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml)
21:43:29,283 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | DefaultListableBeanFactory       | 59 - org.springframework.beans - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@77e77a: defining beans [template,consumerTemplate,camel-1:beanPostProcessor,camel-1,required,jtaTransactionManager,geronimoTransactionManager,activeMQ,jmsConnectionFactory,jmsManagedConnectionFactory,jmsResourceAdapter,jencksConnectionManager,jencksPoolingSupport,requiredBeanForOracleAq,oracleQueue,oracleQueueCredentials,aqConnectionFactoryQueue,aqXADataSource,jdbcXADataSource,managedXADataSource,myTransform,preProps,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0]; root of factory hierarchy
21:43:29,736 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | OsgiSpringCamelContext           | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | JMX enabled. Using ManagedManagementStrategy.
21:43:29,839 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | JtaTransactionManager            | 74 - org.springframework.transaction - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Using JTA UserTransaction: org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl@1f07586
21:43:29,839 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | JtaTransactionManager            | 74 - org.springframework.transaction - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Using JTA TransactionManager: org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl@1f07586
21:43:29,839 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | JtaTransactionManager            | 74 - org.springframework.transaction - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl@1f07586
21:43:30,104 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | OsgiSpringCamelContext           | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | Apache Camel 2.6.0-fuse-01-09 (CamelContext: 202-camel-3) is starting21:43:30,430 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | Activator                        | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | Found 13 @Converter classes to load
21:43:30,469 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | Activator                        | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | Found 1 @Converter classes to load
21:43:30,473 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | Activator                        | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | Found 1 @Converter classes to load
21:43:30,477 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | Activator                        | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | Found 2 @Converter classes to load
21:43:34,173 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | OsgiSpringCamelContext           | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[activeMQ://queue:BROKER2.QUEUE?concurrentConsumers=10]
21:43:34,194 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | OsgiSpringCamelContext           | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
21:43:34,196 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | OsgiSpringCamelContext           | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-01-09 | Apache Camel 2.6.0-fuse-01-09 (CamelContext: 202-camel-3) started in 4.089 seconds
21:43:34,204 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext  | 61 - org.springframework.context - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Publishing application context as OSGi service with properties {org.springframework.context.service.name=camel-osgi-aqmq, Bundle-SymbolicName=camel-osgi-aqmq, Bundle-Version=4.3.0.fuse-03-00}
21:43:34,205 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-5 | ContextLoaderListener            | 72 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.0 | Application context successfully refreshed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=camel-osgi-aqmq, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
21:43:41,674 | INFO  | tenerContainer-7 | SpringInitialContextFactory      | 110 - org.apache.xbean.spring - 3.7 | Loading JNDI context from: class path resource [jndi.xml]
21:43:41,685 | INFO  | tenerContainer-7 | XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader     | 59 - org.springframework.beans - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [jndi.xml]
```

Answer (score 0):

In jndi.xml, you should try :

```
<beans>
  <import resource="beans.xml"/>
(...)
```